# BaseHTTPRequestHandler data outside do_GET

Tags: python, http, server, handler

I want to save some data (query parameter) from `do_GET` to variable in the code and use it outside `do_GET` method and handler class. 
How I can do it when `do_GET` can't return any data and handler is created "on demand"?

It is good idea to save data to file, then read it?
My other (really stupid) idea is to `raise Exception` with data...

I need handle 1 specific request

```
    class CustomRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            token = self.path.rsplit('?code=', 1)[-1]
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.  We have no idea what `do_GET` is.

Comment: do_GET is method that You should implement in handler inheriting BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: Write the data to  file, save it in a global variable, save it in an environment variable, save it in a module attribute...